# Creating new opportunity by formula NEW() and ISCHANGED()

Tags: process-builder

I am using pardot to create/updated an account. When pardot created/updated an account, then in process builder I am creating the an **opportunity** with the values which came from pardot. So to create opportunity I implement two conditions in Process Builder `OR(ISNEW(), ISCHANGED([Account].ArticleTitle))`

I am checking if account new or specific field("ArticleTitle") updated. This formula working fine. I can create **new opportunity** if one of the condition returns `true`. But the problem start with **ISCHANGED** condition. If field changes 5hen builder creates new opp for the account **but** new one takes first opportunity's values for it's own empty fields... Is there a way to prevent this? Why new opportunity takes older opportunities values...

Comment: The problem might be with the immediate actions part and not with the conditions. Can you provide some more details/ screenshots?

Comment: @arut here, this is the immadiate action of creating a opportunity https://imgur.com/a/mmoUM6h

Comment: Looks like nothing wrong with the immediate action too. Have you checked if there are any triggers or field updates that are populating the fields you are concerned about?

Comment: @arut actually, i am not sure. in pardot, when prospect has new opportunity. pardot's updated prospect value copied to new opportinity. of course new opportunity's empty fields takes old opportinity's values too from pardot, but why empty fields takes values too...

Comment: I don't think I would want to confuse this with what is happening in Pardot (given the limited info in this question). Regardless, the prospect is created/ updated in the same DB and the process builder is the one responsible for creating the new opportunity. At this point, I can suggest you to modify the actions in the process builder and observe for any difference in the new opportunities created. Sort of identifying if anything in the process builder is causing this problem or if its completely happening at some other place. BTW, have you checked the debug logs?